# Can you open MS Software application from a link in your SharePoint site?

Tags: 2010

I have some software applications that I use constantly and I would like to be able to open them directly from my SharePoint site quick launch menu. I have access to the .exe file. Is there anyway I can get it to open? The programs are located on my C drive.

I don't have access to central administration settings so that is out of the question. If there is any documentation out there that would be great. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

.exe files are potentialy dangerous so it has realy restricted access. I do not think you'll be able even upload this application to the SharePoint...

In addition SharePoint is rendered in a browser. Even if administrator of the site (he sets extentions possible to use in SharePoint site) allows you to do this only download will be possible of this file. You can do "run" inside the browser but this will give copy to temp folder of your browser...

Hope it helps,

Andrew